# Proving that a derived language is regular

Tags: formal-languages, regular-languages, closure-properties

Suppose I have a DFA recognizing a regular language $L$, how do I prove that 
$$\text{lefthalf}(L)= \{ w_1 \mid \exists w_2 \in \Sigma^* ,w_1w_2 \in L \land \|w_1\| = \|w_2\| \}$$ is also a regular language?

Comment: Welcome to [cs.SE]! Your question is a very basic one. Since you [did 
not include much of an attempt to solve it on your own](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594), we have little to
work with. Let me direct you towards our 
[reference questions](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/599)
which cover your problem in detail.
Please work through the related questions listed there, try to solve your 
problem again and edit to include your attempts along with the specific 
problems you encountered. Your question may then be reopened.
Good luck!

Comment: @Raphael The question http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/1331/how-to-prove-a-language-is-regular is not the same as this one. I would prefer to refer to this question http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/11018/regularity-of-the-exact-middle-of-words-from-a-regular-language

Answer (score 1):

Hint: while reading $w_1$, guess $w_2$ and gather enough information so that in the end you can decide whether $w_1 w_2 \in L$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: while reading $w_1$, guess $w_2$ from the end, and see where you meet in the middle.
Thus you can take as the set of states a subset of $Q^2$.